# Convert XPath result to string

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am going to be converting XML to JSON as described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.xml2json.html). I need to pass that method a string and I can't work out how to convert my XPath result to a string.

I am trying to extract all children of a specific parent element, `[name=bar]`, from an XML file that is formatted like this:

```
    <items>
        <item name="foo">
            <element>1</element>
            <element>
                <child>c1</child>        
            </element>
            <element>2</element>
        </item>
        <item name="bar">
            <element>1</element>
            <element>
                <child>c1</child>        
            </element>
            <element>2</element>
        </item>
    </items>
```

I can access the node I want:

```
    $xmlfile = simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml');
    $item = $productsXml->xpath('//item[@name="bar"]'); // Returns an array
```

I would like to convert the result to a string:

```
        <item name="bar">
            <element>1</element>
            <element>
                <child>c1</child>        
            </element>
            <element>2</element>
        </item>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `implode()` function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the XPath results and then use [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) to save the node to a variable as a string:

```
$str = ''; // initializing empty string to append to 
$item = $xmlfile->xpath('//item[@name="bar"]');
while(list(,$node) = each($item)) { // getting each node
    $str .= $node->asXML(); // save it to $str
}    
echo $str;
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54576)

Comment: Hi thank you for that. Funnily enough I noticed that I had done that before but didn't htmlentities the result so I couldn't see it!! lol

Comment: @beingalex: You're welcome. Just a sidenote: you can always use `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to just display the text content without any formatting. Cheers :)